# Expected value of bernouilli times a centred normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've trouble concerning a "simple" calculus. There are two variables: $X\sim Normal(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim Bernouilli(p)$,

EDIT: $X$ and $Y$ are independents.

And, we defined a third one as: $Z = X \times Y$.

What is the expected value: $\mathbb{E}(-Z \times Z)$? I did the following stuff, but the result seems wrong:

$\mathbb{E}(-Z \times Z)=-\mathbb{E}( Z^2)=-Cov(|Z|,|Z|)-\mathbb{E}( |Z|)\mathbb{E}( |Z|)=-Var(Y|X|)-\mathbb{E}^2( Y|X|)$.

Therefore, I have:

$Var(Y|X|)=\mathbb{E}(|X|^2)\mathbb{E}( Y^2)-\mathbb{E}^2(|X|)\mathbb{E}^2(Y)=\sigma^2p - \mathbb{E}^2(|X|)p^2$

$\mathbb{E}^2( Y|X|)=Cov(Y,|X|) + \mathbb{E}( Y)\mathbb{E}( |X|)=Cov(Y,|X|)+p\mathbb{E}( |X|)$

Giving: $\mathbb{E}(-Z Z)=-\sigma^2p + \mathbb{E}^2(|X|)p^2 - Cov(Y,|X|)-p\mathbb{E}( |X|)$.

But I should find: $-p\mathbb{E}^2(|X|)$. What could I do?

Comment: by $\times$ do you mean the usual product?

Comment: Are you sure that $-\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = -\text{Cov}(|Z|, |Z|)$? Why?

Comment: and how in the world can $X$ and $Y$ be iid if they follow two different distributions?

Comment: you're right. thank you.

Comment: I suspect $X$ and $Y$ independents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}
E[Z^2]&=&E[X^2Y^2]\\
&=&E[X^2]E[Y^2]\\
&=&(Var(X)+E[X]^2)(Var(Y)+E[Y]^2)\\
&=&(\sigma^2+0)(pq+p^2)\\
&=&\sigma^2p(q+p)\\
&=&\sigma^2p
\end{eqnarray}$

Thus $E[-Z^2]=-\sigma^2 p=-\sigma^2E[Y]=-pE[X^2]$

Comment: Thank you. But it seems I should obtain $E[-Z^2] = -p E^2[X]$, meaning that in this situation $E[X^2]=E^2[X]$... but I doubt.

Comment: It is not reasonable the term $E^2[X]$, cause since $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then $E^2[X]=0$ (notation: $E^2[X]=E[X]^2$).